# Histogram binwidth (in)consistency between base graphics and ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I ran into the following scenario...

The following code produce the 2 identical histogram:

```
library(ggplot2)
data("diamonds")    
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=1000)
qplot(price, data = diamonds, binwidth = 1000)
```

However, I do not understand how they derive the first bar/bin on the left, in fact, the whole histogram seems wrong to me.
[image]

On the other hand:

```
hist(diamonds$price,breaks = seq(0,20000, by=1000))
```

produces the following graph which seems right to me:
[image]

To validate the data I ran this code:

```
br = seq(0,20000,by=1000)

ranges = paste(head(br,-1), br[-1], sep=" - ")
freq = hist(diamonds$price, breaks = br, include.lowest=TRUE, plot=FALSE)

data.frame(range = ranges, frequency = freq$counts)
```

and it produces:

```
           range frequency
1       0 - 1000     14524
2    1000 - 2000      9683
3    2000 - 3000      6129
4    3000 - 4000      4225
5    4000 - 5000      4665
...
```

So where does that first bar/bin in `ggplot` or `qplot` come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ggplot histogram bars are centered on 0, 1000, 2000, etc., whereas the base histogram bars are centered on 500, 1500, 2500, etc. To check this, compare the bar counts in each histogram with table counts where we set the breaks explicitly.

```
table(cut(diamonds$price, breaks=seq(-500,20000,1000)))
```

> ```
> (-500,500]       (500,1.5e+03]   (1.5e+03,2.5e+03]   (2.5e+03,3.5e+03]   (3.5e+03,4.5e+03] 
>       1749               18261                7532                4958                4535
> etc.
> ```

```
theme_set(theme_classic())
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1000, fill="grey80", colour="black", lwd=0.2) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1000, geom="text", aes(label=..count..),
           position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3)
```

[image]

And for the base histogram:

```
freq = hist(diamonds$price)$counts
tab = unname(table(cut(diamonds$price, breaks=seq(0,19000,1000))))

cbind(freq, tab)
```

> ```
>        freq   tab
>  [1,] 14524 14524
>  [2,]  9683  9683
>  [3,]  6129  6129
>  [4,]  4225  4225
>  [5,]  4665  4665
>  [6,]  3163  3163
>  [7,]  2278  2278
>  [8,]  1668  1668
>  [9,]  1307  1307
> [10,]  1076  1076
> [11,]   934   934
> [12,]   825   825
> [13,]   701   701
> [14,]   603   603
> [15,]   504   504
> [16,]   513   513
> [17,]   425   425
> [18,]   405   405
> [19,]   312   312
> ```

To get the same breaks in the ggplot histogram, you can use the `center` argument in addition to `binwidth`:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1000, center=500, fill="grey80", colour="black", lwd=0.2) +
  stat_bin(binwidth=1000, center=500, geom="text", aes(label=..count..), 
           position=position_stack(vjust=0.5), size=3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @eipi10. However, it doesn't seem like ggplot always center on 0  for the first bar. If I do: ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=price)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=500), the plot starts at 0 (center on 250). That doesn't seem consistent, is there a reason behind that?

Comment: When I set `binwidth=500`, the first bin is centered on 500 and goes from 250 to 750. I'm not sure exactly how the ggplot bin-setting algorithm works, but it seems to try to center a bin on zero if there is at least one value within a bin centered at zero (given whatever binwidth the user chooses or the default binwidth (which is calculated based a default of 30 bins) otherwise).